# How to remove a line from tile image using ImageMagick

Tags: ubuntu

I used this image to make tile:

And I used the command in ubuntu terminal is:

```
montage 4.jpg +clone +clone +clone -tile x4 -geometry +0+0 _1col.jpg

montage 4.jpg +clone +clone +clone -tile 4x4 -geometry +0+0 _1col.jpg
```

And my output image is below:

But image is not seen a single image. A line is seen in image. How to make this image as seen like single image.

Comment: You have gradiants rather than solid colours and the columns are not all the same width at the top and bottom. As you can see the left hand side is better

Answer (score 0):

As Bonzo said, your image is not symmetric between the pairs of lines. You have a single line on the left side and not enough space on the right side. You can remove the single line on the left and replace with similar size space as between the other pairs of lines. So in Imagemagick, you can do the following. But this will not remove the vertical gradient in your original image.

```
convert 4.jpg -gravity west -chop 4x0 -gravity east -chop 1x0 \( +clone -gravity west -crop 3x83+0+0 +repage -flop \) +swap +append miff:- | montage - -duplicate 15 -tile 4x4 -geometry +0+0 test.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I cropped the image and made line symmetry. Now my problem is solve.

Comment: `@arun` If you are satisfied with my answer, please consider giving it a upvote.